# How can I fix duplication of key constraints in c#?

Tags: c#

Here is my code ,

```
//Set  the property AllowUserToAddRows to false will prevent a new empty row
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

//registration of students 
connect.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableStudents(Student_ID,Fullname,Gender,Course,Year,Section,Guardian,Contact,Address)VALUES('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox4.Text + "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox2.Text + "','" + ComboBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

connect.Close();
```

when I try to click my register button , an blank space in my datagridview occur,, then how do i fix the register button if it's always adding a blank space in datagridview either prompt some warning
[image]

Comment: set your primary key to **Auto Increase** in DB and delete this id from Insert Into

Comment: Welcome to SO, I think when you get a primary key from your user it will be common that it throws duplication exception! So, What is your plan if its Id already exists?

Comment: Read up on SQL Injection. Composing a SQL query with raw user input is one of the easiest ways to write a security vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the Student_ID field as Primary Key in your database then you need not include it in your insert statement and you can simply exclude or make that field invisible in you Datagrid:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TableStudents(Fullname,Gender,Course,Year,Section,Guardian,Contact,Address)VALUES(textBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox4.Text + "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox2.Text + "','" + ComboBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

do this steps to resolve your problem

1_Set your primary key to `AutoIncrease` In Database

2_Change your code like this

```
"INSERT INTO TableStudents(Fullname,Gender,Course,Year,Section,Guardian,Contact,Address)VALUES(textBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox4.Text + "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox2.Text + "','" + ComboBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')";
```

Remove `Student_ID` and `textBox2.Text`

Comment: is this going to display the student id ? because i need to display this in my output

Comment: yeah you can get this when binding your grid and not use when you want Insert into db